# Javascript to parse URL parameter - not always working

Tags: javascript, parsing, google-tag-manager

I'm very new to JavaScript so please excuse the simplicity of this question. I am trying to parse a URL parameter using Google Tag Manager and have created the below custom JavaScript:

```html
function(){
var queryString = {{Page URL}};
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
var deposit = urlParams.get('deposit')
return deposit;
}
```

In my test environment the script has returned the correct value a couple of times when I have simplified the URL. In the real environment the URL contains a # and the parameter I'm trying to parse is the first parameter and so follows "?" - my successful attempts have all been when I've inserted other parameters and so the parameter I want moves to following "&"

Could it be the inclusion of "#" within the URL that is causing the issue or is there an issue with the script I've written?

Many thanks in advance.

Nicky

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `window.location.search` instead of the full URL to the URLSearchParams constructor. It expects a string of a format like `"?test=56&example=apples"` (not `"http://example.org?test=56&example=apples#someAnchor"`). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams for more information.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you very much for your input. I had tried window.location.search initially without any luck which is why I'd moved to {{Page URL}}.

Comment: Could you explain the results/issues you got when using window.location.search? It seems to solve my understanding of the problem correctly

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm getting the value returned as null. I should add that the form submission that triggers the parameter opens a new tab if that would cause an issue? Thanks